# Tic Tac Toe in Browser Console

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, console, tic-tac-toe

Anyone remember "War games?"

I have a very long way to go, but I thought it would be interesting to make a version of Tic Tac Toe which plays itself. At present the AI is "choose a random available space" (i.e nonexistent). I will build on that later, but for now I would value some feedback on my basic approach. I've used an object literal pattern, which seems to make sense for the task. I'm curious to learn about any improvements I could make in terms of the structure and implementation. Also, what did I do well please? Is there anything obviously amateurish about my approach?

```js
const TicTacToe = {

    setup: function() {

        this.player1 = {
            name: "Crosses",
            symbol: "X"
        };
        this.player2 = {
            name: "Naughts",
            symbol: "0"
        };

        this.restart();
    },

    restart: function() {
        this.board = [
            [ "", "", "" ],
            [ "", "", "" ],
            [ "", "", "" ]
        ];

        this.currentPlayer = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 ) == 0 ? this.player1 : this.player2;
        this.playRound();
    },

    playRound: function() {
        console.log( this.currentPlayer.name + " start." );
        while ( !this.isWinningCombination( this.player1.symbol, this.board ) && !this.isWinningCombination( this.player2.symbol, this.board ) && !this.isDraw( this.board ) ) {
            this.sleep( 500 );
            this.playerTurn( this.currentPlayer );
        }
    },

    playerTurn: function( player ) {
        while ( true ) {
            let pos = [ Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ), Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) ];
            if ( this.board[ pos[ 0 ] ][ pos[ 1 ] ] == "" ) {
                this.board[ pos[ 0 ] ][ pos[ 1 ] ] = player.symbol;
                this.displayBoard( this.board );
                if ( this.isWinningCombination( player.symbol, this.board ) ) {
                    console.log( this.currentPlayer.name + " win!" )
                    this.playAgainDialogue();
                } else if ( this.isDraw( this.board ) ) {
                    console.log( "It's a draw" );
                    this.playAgainDialogue();
                }
                this.currentPlayer = this.currentPlayer == this.player1 ? this.player2 : this.player1;
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
    },

    displayBoard: function( board ) {
        display = "";

        // First row
        display += board[ 0 ][ 0 ] == "" ? "  " : ` ${board[0][0]}`;
        display += "|";
        display += board[ 0 ][ 1 ] == "" ? " " : `${board[0][1]}`;
        display += "|";
        display += board[ 0 ][ 2 ] == "" ? "  \n" : `${board[0][2]}\n`;

        // Filler
        display += "--|-|--\n";

        // Second row
        display += board[ 1 ][ 0 ] == "" ? "  " : ` ${board[1][0]}`;
        display += "|";
        display += board[ 1 ][ 1 ] == "" ? " " : `${board[1][1]}`;
        display += "|";
        display += board[ 1 ][ 2 ] == "" ? "  \n" : `${board[1][2]}\n`;

        // Filler
        display += "--|-|--\n";

        // Third row
        display += board[ 2 ][ 0 ] == "" ? "  " : ` ${board[2][0]}`;
        display += "|";
        display += board[ 2 ][ 1 ] == "" ? " " : `${board[2][1]}`;
        display += "|";
        display += board[ 2 ][ 2 ] == "" ? "  \n" : `${board[2][2]}\n`;
        console.log( display );
        console.log( "" );
    },

    // Check for win
    isWinningCombination: function( symbol, board ) {
        return [ // Rows
            board[ 0 ][ 0 ] === symbol && board[ 0 ][ 1 ] === symbol && board[ 0 ][ 2 ] === symbol,
            board[ 1 ][ 0 ] === symbol && board[ 1 ][ 1 ] === symbol && board[ 1 ][ 2 ] === symbol,
            board[ 2 ][ 0 ] === symbol && board[ 2 ][ 1 ] === symbol && board[ 2 ][ 2 ] === symbol,

            // Columns
            board[ 0 ][ 0 ] === symbol && board[ 1 ][ 0 ] === symbol && board[ 2 ][ 0 ] === symbol,
            board[ 0 ][ 1 ] === symbol && board[ 1 ][ 1 ] === symbol && board[ 2 ][ 1 ] === symbol,
            board[ 0 ][ 2 ] === symbol && board[ 1 ][ 2 ] === symbol && board[ 2 ][ 2 ] === symbol,

            // Diagonals
            board[ 0 ][ 0 ] === symbol && board[ 1 ][ 1 ] === symbol && board[ 2 ][ 2 ] === symbol,
            board[ 0 ][ 2 ] === symbol && board[ 1 ][ 1 ] === symbol && board[ 2 ][ 0 ] === symbol
        ].
        includes( true );
    },

    isDraw: function( board ) {
        return !this.isWinningCombination( this.player1.symbol, board ) && !this.isWinningCombination( this.player2.symbol, board ) && !this.board.some( row => row.includes( "" ) );
    },

    // Terrible practice, they say.
    sleep: function( delay ) {
        const start = new Date().getTime();
        while ( new Date().getTime() < start + delay );
    },

    playAgainDialogue : function(){
        console.log("Type TicTacToe.restart() to play again");
    }
};

TicTacToe.setup();
```

```html
<h1>Please open your console to start</h1>
```

Please note the snippet behaves differently to running in a browser (no "sleep" functionality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What you did right

It's good that you designed an object,
and that you separated some operations to functions.
I think it would be good to go further:
more dedicated objects,
smaller functions,
helper functions.
More on all that below.

#### Decompose to smaller functions

The `playerTurn` function looks really complex,
with deeply nested code:
a `while (true)` outer loop,
and then nested conditionals.

Try to split to smaller steps. The steps performed by this function:

1. Find randomly an available position
2. Mark the player's symbol on the board
3. Check if the game is over

If you move the first step to a dedicated function,
you get a much simpler loop:

```
findEmptyPos: function() {
    while (true) {
        let pos = Pos.create(randomInt(3), randomInt(3));
        if (this.board.isEmpty(pos)) return pos;
    }
}
```

Thanks to this new function,
the `playerTurn` will no longer have a complex `while` loop in it.

Note that I extracted the repeated `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)` calls to a helper function call `randomInt(3)`.
It's good to avoid duplicated code, much less to type, and with good descriptive names, easier and less to read.

I also replaced other elements:

- Position used to be represented as an array of two elements. It worked, but it's a lazy solution with several flaws: the index 0 and 1 by themselves don't mean anything, and also nothing prevents you from assigning to other indexes. It probably makes sense to create a proper `Pos` abstraction, with `row` and `col` fields. Those fields will have meaning thanks to their names.
- The check if a position is empty used verbose code like `this.board[pos[0]][pos[1]] == ""`, comparing to a hardcoded value.
  Instead of that, it's better to have a `Board` abstraction with an `isEmpty` function, that would encapsulate and hide the implementation detail that "empty" is represented as an empty string.

Lastly in the `playerTurn` function,
this snippet is a bit unfortunate:

> ```
> if ( this.isWinningCombination( player.symbol, this.board ) ) {
>     console.log( this.currentPlayer.name + " win!" )
>     this.playAgainDialogue();
> } else if ( this.isDraw( this.board ) ) {
>     console.log( "It's a draw" );
>     this.playAgainDialogue();
> }
> this.currentPlayer = this.currentPlayer == this.player1 ? this.player2 : this.player1;
> ```

That is,
why let the `this.currentPlayer` switch take place after calling `this.playAgainDialogue();`?
It doesn't seem to make sense,
and that the `if` and `else if` there should have had a `break`.

#### Short-circuit evaluation

This may seem kind of clever, but it's not:

> ```
> return [ // Rows
>     board[ 0 ][ 0 ] === symbol && board[ 0 ][ 1 ] === symbol && board[ 0 ][ 2 ] === symbol,
>     board[ 1 ][ 0 ] === symbol && board[ 1 ][ 1 ] === symbol && board[ 1 ][ 2 ] === symbol,
>     board[ 2 ][ 0 ] === symbol && board[ 2 ][ 1 ] === symbol && board[ 2 ][ 2 ] === symbol,
>
>     // Columns
>     ...
> ].
> includes( true );
> ```

The problem is that *all* the conditions in the array are computer,
*and then* the `includes(...)` will return when it finds the first that was `true`. That's too late.
If instead of creating an array,
you had chained the conditions with `||` then short-circuiting would apply,
and once there is a match (any winning row, or column, etc),
the remaining conditions would not be evaluated.

#### Benefit more from `this`

Some parameters are passed around to functions,
most noticeably `this.board`,
when those functions could access the board via `this.board`.
You can safely remove such parameters and access the values directly.

#### Simplify printing

The printing of the board is very tedious and error-prone.
Let's take a closer look at this:

> ```
> // First row
> display += board[ 0 ][ 0 ] == "" ? "  " : ` ${board[0][0]}`;
> display += "|";
> display += board[ 0 ][ 1 ] == "" ? " " : `${board[0][1]}`;
> display += "|";
> display += board[ 0 ][ 2 ] == "" ? "  \n" : `${board[0][2]}\n`;
> ```

For `board[0][0]` there is a space prefix in both branches of the ternary.
For `board[0][2]` there is a `\n` in both branches of the ternary.
=> It's better to not repeat characters in both branches of ternaries, for example:

```
// First row
display += " " + (board[ 0 ][ 0 ] == "" ? " " : `${board[0][0]}`);
display += "|";
display += board[ 0 ][ 1 ] == "" ? " " : `${board[0][1]}`;
display += "|";
display += (board[ 0 ][ 2 ] == "" ? " " : `${board[0][2]}`) + "\n";
```

Now the lines look more similar.
When things look similar,
they make you think of further generalization opportunities.

You could benefit more from the `` `...` `` strings in JavaScript,
and also of the fallback values with `|| ...`:

```
// First row
display += ` ${board[0][0] || ' '}`;
display += "|";
display += `${board[0][1] || ' '}`;
display += "|";
display += `${board[0][2] || ' '}\n`;
```

#### Minor technical issues

- The last statement in the `while` loop of `playerTurn` is `continue`. That's pointless and should be removed.
- Some lines are extremely long. It's hard to read code like that, better to split to multiple lines.
- In `displayBoard` you forgot to use the `let` keyword for the `display` variable.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for. Thank you.